# Click on field to reload report with clicked field value as parameter

Tags: parameters, hyperlink, crystal-reports

I have a field on my report which when clicked on, I would like it to become the new parameter value of the report and refresh the data. I am using Crystal Reports 2008.  Hyperlink seems like the right idea but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: didnt get your requirement... can you elaborate with an example?

Comment: I will sure try.  So my report's only parameter is a string which pulls up any record where the field TEXT_ID equals the parameter (?textID).  One of the fields on the report is the PARENT_TEXT_ID which is the parent record of the current record.  What i would like to do is be able to click on that PARENT_TEXT_ID report field have have the report refresh with the PARENT_TEXT_ID as the new parameter.  I could do this with a sub-report but then i could only do this action once.  I would like to be able to keep clicking on the PARENT_TEXT_ID to travel through it's history.  Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
To extent I know the crystal report... below is my approach
```

if you are using Crystal as a standalone application... then what approach you have followed is correct... use sub report.

To ge the Hyperlink I suggest to use `onDemand` sub report... Let me know If I miss anything

Comment: OK I feel silly - you are 100% right and for whatever reason it didn't occur to me that passing the same report as it's on-demand subreport would work since i thought you could only have a sub-report one level deep.

Comment: I do notice that when i click the hyperlink for the sub-report - the hyperlink disappears on the report.  I'll play with this a bit more though.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What I have suggested is use sub report as a hyperlink from a main report but not from a sub report....I hope you got my point..

Comment: Yes that's what I'm doing - which works well.  It's a laboratory sample database where most samples are a sub-sample or were created from another sample.  that's what the PARENT_TEXT_ID is, it is the ID of what sample the current sample came from.  I was hoping to use this report to keep clicking on the parent_text_id hyperlink to keep going back through each parent without having to manually type or select a parameter value.

Comment: I believe that the sub-report limitations will limit me to only go back one step in a samples history without manually entering a new sample text_id.  it is useful as it is though so thanks again for your help.